# Winlogon Application Error

Tags: windows, windows-xp, ghost

This error is happening to 6 out of 32 computers. I have created a base image from scratch using Ghost Enterprise, but error still shows on the same machines. It happens at the log on prompt and after doing a soft reset the message goes away, but it comes back eventually.

-Error message-

The Instruction at "0X74eF400e" referenced Memory at "0X00000000" The memory could not be "Written".

Winlogon.exe - Application Error

Any reason why this is happening? I have tried to run a memTest but everything shows okay.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

1. Anything showing up in the Event log?
2. Update to service pack 3, if it is not already.

Comment: Event log doesn't show anything regarding that error. I've been thinking about upgrading to SP3 since i seen somthing similar on Micrsofts website. But do you have any idea why its only happening to certain machines? I would understand if it was all 323 computers getting the error massage but only 6..?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issues. Some 10 out of 30 computers got the winlogon.exe error. 0X74eF400e" referenced Memory at "0X00000000.

I'm not using Ghost, but we push out VMware-images. It is a Red Hat 4.x platform with Vmware 5.x.x. (lately upgraded, but still have the problem) and we push out Windows XP SP2 images.

(With this method we've had problems with outher bluescreens too but they might be gone withe the VMware-upgrade.)

- windows does not create a Minidump for the crasches.
- problems often disappears after a few reboots and then the machines runs fine for weeks.
- when we patch windows XP the problems often returns and sometimes it helps to reinstall VMware Tools...but not always...

For a time I was sure that running "the same" image on several virtual machines in a domain was the issue, but I have installed windows (not using the image) in Vmware on a few systems and that does not help on all of them...

By installing "Debuging Tools for Windows" an running the tlist -command in cmd I'm now trying to find the responsible .dll -file in winlogon.exe but so far; no luck.

- Somehow related to images right??
- domain? yes?
- somehow random...